# "Invalid File" error while clicking the image in SD Card(android)

Tags: android, image, file-upload, mms

I need to send MMS in android so had given the code as below, the images from drawable is first saved in sd card then fetched back to the SMS body, but after clicking "SEND" button  i get the image as shown here. the saved images in downloads from sd card are not openable, i get error as "invalid file". checked with the image name everything is in lowercase alphabets.
where am i going wrong please let me know.

[image]

**Intent code**

```
private void doSendIntent(String subject, String text) {
      try {
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   // sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text); 
   sendIntent.setType("image/png");

   Bitmap bbicon;

    bbicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.gicon);


    String extStorageDirectory = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    File f = new File(extStorageDirectory + "/Download/",
            "gicon.png");
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bbicon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    File fl = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath() + "/Download/", "gicon.png");

    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(fl);     
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
   this.cordova).getContext().getPackageName(), 0);
               this.cordova.startActivityForResult(this, sendIntent, 0); 
   }
   private Resources getResources() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

  }
```

Logcat Error

```
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323): IOException caught while opening or reading stream
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Download/gicon.png (Permission denied)
09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):   at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
  09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:80)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:132)
09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):   at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:317)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at com.android.mms.model.MediaModel.initMediaSize(MediaModel.java:280)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at com.android.mms.model.MediaModel.<init>(MediaModel.java:77)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at com.android.mms.model.RegionMediaModel.<init>(RegionMediaModel.java:40)
09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):   at com.android.mms.model.RegionMediaModel.<init>(RegionMediaModel.java:35)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at com.android.mms.model.ImageModel.<init>(ImageModel.java:63)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.changeMedia(WorkingMessage.java:464)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at com.android.mms.data.WorkingMessage.setAttachment(WorkingMessage.java:365)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.addImage(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2663)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.addAttachment(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2799)
09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):   at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.handleSendIntent(ComposeMessageActivity.java:2728)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.initialize(ComposeMessageActivity.java:1757)
09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):   at com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity.onCreate(ComposeMessageActivity.java:1685)
09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 09-20 11:58:35.200: E/Mms/media(323):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: have you used <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> permission in your manifest?

Comment: yes like this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> @Zax

Comment: Are you sure there are no error when you flush the Bitmap (you catch the error without any log or `e.printStackTrace()`). Secondly, have you tried to open the file with any file explorer?

Comment: Can you post the complete error that you are getting. Also, the error you are getting is in runtime or compile time?

Comment: can you just tryout this: File fl = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Download/", "gicon.png"); Because you have not specified getAbsolutepath() while saving the image. Just try this one.

Comment: Still getting the same.. my images from drawable are getting saved in Downloads folder in sdcard @Zax

Comment: Are you able to open it from SDcard, i mean using your file explorer?

Comment: @DD. all needed permission is added in manifest??

Comment: yes added. but dont know why the above is not displaing properly  @PiyushGupta

Comment: replace your path and lemme know; `File fl = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Download" + "/gicon.png"`

Comment: same output @RobinHood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since i'm not using oncreate method in this class so was getting error at getResouces() so had given `private Resources getResources() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}` in order to clear the error. and this was making the image not to appear.
so now deleted the above code and gave `bbicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.cordova.getActivity().getResources(),` which solved my error.

Answer (score 2):

This is one function that i used for saving `Bitmap`. However i didn't try opening it programatically, rather i tried opening it from my file manager and i was able to view it fine. Modifying the code for your use:

```
//Global variable path
path=null;
private void SaveIamge(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"\Downloads\";
    String fname = "gicon.png";
    File file = new File (path, fname);
    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
    try {
           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is how you can call the above function:

```
Bitmap bbicon;

bbicon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.gicon);

SaveIamge(bbicon);

//use the initialized path variable to convert path to uri
try{
       File fl = new File(path,"gicon.png");
       Uri myURI= Uri.fromFile(fl);
       /*rest of your code*/
}
catch(Exception e)
{
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope this Helps!!!